# How to version/update AssemblyInfo.cs of assemblies shared by others that are deployed independent?

Tags: c#, svn, versioning, assemblyinfo, teamcity-5.1

I've got a legacy solution with multiple project references.

Two of those projects are deployed independently, and both reference the other projects.

Currently the versioning is purely manual, but I'd like to automate the process (of updating the version number of AssemblyInfo.cs).

We're using Visual Studio 2010, SVN, and TeamCity, and already have a proven way of updating the version numbers for other solutions. However, those solutions only have one version number to consider, whilst this solution have to.

One way could be to update the two important, i.e. the reason for deployment, numbers automatically, and update the others manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try : [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx#CommandLineUtility)

*Command line-utility supports VC++ 6.0 DSW files as well as VS2002/2003/2005/2008 SLN files. It shares configuration settings with the add-in version, but user can override these settings with appropriate startup switches. Please check CommandLine.txt file included in the setup for a brief description and list of startup switches.
During command-line utility setup, corresponding menu with two items are added to Programs menu. "AutoVer" entry starts the command-line utility with /g switch, opening the same GUI as the add-in does.*